# Problems with MySQL [Minecraft]

Tags: networking, mysql, timeout, phpmyadmin, minecraft

I get an error with MySQL. My servers crash every day having something to do about Java. But this one was different.

Error: http://pastebin.com/n2xLY50L

Edit: I also have two values put in my my.cnf, I don't know if this would effect it. http://pastebin.com/KLqDbsCR

The values are

```
wait_timeout = 604800
interactive_timeout = 604800
```

Answer (score 0):

You said you placed those two valued in the file. Why did you place those values in? Are they in the right location in the file? Try putting those two lines at the end or start of the file. Looking at the error it seems as if the MySQL connection can't be established. Try these and let me know.